# Ajax and Masonry

Tags: php, ajax, load, jquery-masonry

Hi guys I have a little issue here I want to use this code for load more

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var page = 1;
    var pages = $("#pages").val();

    $("#content").load("resources/more.php");
    $("#loadmore").bind("click", function(){
        var next = page+=1;

        $.get("resources/more.php?page="+next, function(data){
            var el = jQuery(data);
            if(next==pages){

                $("#loadmore").remove();
            }
            $("#content").append(el).masonry( 'appended', el, true );
                    //$("#content").append(el).masonry( 'reload' );
        });
    });
    });
```

Load more is working quite fine nevertheless Masonry isn't working at all. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due to a bug I helped find! It turns out that $.get() returns the HTML with some underlying DOM structure that Masonry doesn't like.

To fix it, change this:

```
var el = jQuery(data);
```

To this:

```
var el = jQuery(data).filter('div');
```

You can read more about it here:
https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/374